# Select Distinct, Order By Non-Returned Column Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have the following table:

```
Col_A:    Col_B:    Col_C:
Item1     Value1    A
Item2     Value2    B
Item3     Value3    A
Item4     Value4    B
Item5     Value5    A
Item1     Value1    A
```

Now, what I am looking to get back is `Distinct` values from `Col A` & `Col B` ordered by `Col C` then `Col A`, so the result would look like:

```
Col_A:    Col_B:
Item1     Value1
Item3     Value3
Item5     Value5
Item2     Value2
Item4     Value4
```

The SQL I intended to use for this was:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT [Col_A], [Col_B] 
 FROM [MyTable] 
      WHERE ...
 ORDER BY [Col_C] ASC, [Col_A] ASC
```

But I get the error:

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

I understand why the error is occurring and figure I could solve it with a fairly complex SQL / CTE, but I'm hoping there's a nice, clean & effienct way to write the SQL to get the result I'm looking for...

Comment: If you don't mind a nested subquery that's an easy fix.

Comment: What happens if you have a row like this: `'Item1', 'Value1', 'D'`?, it conflicts with the previous one since it has a different value for `Col_C`

Comment: SELECT [Col_A], [Col_B] FROM ( your query )

Comment: @Love2Learn, I don't mind that and tried, but it gave me problems with the `Order By` part... Truly I'm ok with anything so long as it's effienct and good practice

Comment: @Lamak, that's exactly the problem - I only care about Distinct rows of `ColA` and `ColB`, so if `ColC` is different for matching A & B, I'd only want one record returned.

Comment: @JohnBustos I understand that, but you said that you want them **ordered** byt `Col_C`, so, if I add that row to your sample data, where does it go on your results?

Comment: Oh, @Lamak - Truly, in that case, I wouldn't mind if it went with `D` OR `A`...

Comment: @JohnBustos Then why order your results by that column at all?

Comment: @Lamak, it shouldn't be too often that that situation would occur (if ever), but I need the results to be ordered by that column to keep the daat grouped in a certain way for the rest of my program. Thanks for your helpand insights on this!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no `col_c` in your `select` clause.  With `distinct` you can only order by columns that are in the `select` statement.

Instead, you should use a `group by` statement:

```
select col_a, col_b
from t
group by col_a, col_b
order by max(col_c), col_a
```

In fact, `select distinct` is not necessary at all in SQL.  It is syntactic short-hand for grouping by all the variables.

Comment: Excellent solution! One thing: I think it needs order by `min(col_c)` rather than `max` - that yields the exact order that John was looking for.

Comment: Agreed, +1, I've used `CASE` statements in `ORDER BY`s, but I've never used an aggregated column. Makes perfect sense that you could, just never have.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is right now...

```
SELECT  [Col_A], [Col_B]
FROM   (SELECT  [Col_A], [Col_B], Min([Col_C]) As bah
        FROM    [MyTable] 
        WHERE   ...
        Group   By [Col_A], [Col_B]) n
ORDER   BY bah ASC, [Col_A] ASC
```

Comment: This SHOULD be ok, my only **slight** reservation is what if there's a distinct record for the `ColA` `ColB` `ColC`, but when you remove `ColC`, you end up with a duplicate??

Comment: This works, but I upvoted @GordonLinoff's because his is better.

Answer (score 0):

Select  col_a, col_b from yourtable
Group by col_a, col_ b
Order by min(col_c), col_a

Sorry i missed order by

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your answer... Where does the `Order By` clause fit in??

Comment: @johnbustos i updated answer but i guess i am late now. Sorry i missed order by

Comment: Can you explain exactly what `ORDER BY min(col_c)` accomplishes?

Comment: @aaronbertrand honestly i referred this link  http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/12/13/select-distinct-order-by-error.aspx